# did not find any relations after pg_dump postgresql

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, pg-dump

I have created a database with one table then it is dumped by pg_dump command.

Here is my command

```
pg_dump  -p 5432 mytestdb > dbname.bak.
```

Then i have created another table restore with pg_dump command.
Here is my restore command.

```
pg_dump  -p 5432 mytestdb1 < dbname.bak.
```

When I check `\dt` on `mytestdb` it works fine but from mytestdb1 it shows "did not find any relations"

I checked my .bak file and it has all query rightly. i also check Access privileges.

here is it
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pg_dump` does not "restore" anything. The output of `pg_dump` is a SQL script.

[As documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/backup-dump.html#BACKUP-DUMP-RESTORE) you need to "run" that using `psql` in order to actually restore the data.

```
psql -p 5432 mytestdb1 -f dbname.bak
```